Must a very large nucleus be spherical?
As we do know, residual nuclear force has short distance action so there is no total center to rim nuclear force aggregation inside the nucleus as in the case of for example gravitation in the case of astrophysical body. So there should not be a constant similar force acting on the surface, no matter what position of a point we think about. EM force is only repulsive so even in that case, there is nothing to force the core to make of itself an even sphere. So is there a proof or evidence that a nucleus consisting of more than 50 baryons could be probably irregularly shaped, for example, like a rugby football?

"Deformed" nuclei are well known. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeformation

There are textbooks on nuclear physics that covers the very many nuclear models, of which the deformation type of nuclei are explored as you want to consider. There are so many of them that it makes no sense for us to supply you with them. I can only tell you that for the smallest nuclei, such deviations from spherical-ness is not tolerated. Only when they are heavy enough will such deviations possibly exist, and even there, it tends to be a sign of impending fission.

https://www.science.org/doi/epdf/10.1126/science.129.3346.361

If it's very very big it can even be multiple disconnected spheres (that are topologically very different from a single sphere or even a deformed potato) :D

Although "big" nuclei strive towards a spherical shape, there are many examples where they are instead oblate or football-shaped.
In some cases, it is possible to prepare a nucleus in a nonspherical state. called a "shape isomer". Some such nuclei will spontaneously decay (with a characteristic half-life) to a more-spherical shape and emit a powerful gamma-ray photon in the process. Technetium-99 is one such example and is used for radiotherapy and for producing short-lived radioactive biological tracers.
